# Dynamic Data Validation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, data-validation

I want to restrict a value in a cell based on another cell in the same row.

The value in A must not exceed what is in B. If the value in B is zero, any figure is allowed in A

```
A | B
---
4 | 9     – allowed

5 | 0     – allowed

6 | 5     – the value in A should not be allowed
```

How to set up data validation for this in column A.

I want all rows in Column A to have this validation rule.

Comment: I tried  data validation -> formula      =a1 <= B1     --- nor worked - blocking any change to cell (more or less than B1)

Comment: The validation formula =a1<=b1 is working in a blank sheet. But, I have some vlookup formula in in a1 and b1. When I want to change the value in A1 by overwriting the vlookup function, I want the entered value must not exceed B1 (which is result of another vlookup function)

Answer (score 2):

Set the data validation for A1 as follow:

- On **Cell range** set the cell range from Column A.
- On the **Criteria** dropdown select: Custom formula is
- On the formula input box add this formula:  `=OR(B1=0,A1<=B1)`
- On the **On invalid data** radio buttons selet **Reject input**

Dont' forget to click **Save**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If values in **A1** & **B1** cells output values as a result of formulae this won't be possible to "restrict" via Data Validation. In such cases, the common practice is to wrap your formulae in **`IF`** statement and direct it towards outputting nothing or error if the condition is not met. **A1** then be like:

```
=IF(B1=0, your_A1_vlookup_formula_here, 
 IF(your_A1_vlookup_formula_here>B1, , your_A1_vlookup_formula_here))
```

Comment: The formula is getting the value all right. But, what I want is data validation. The user must not be allowed to increase the value of A1 (by typing in a value) which more than B1 (the Bi is hidden from the user). A1 and B1 are both having a vlookup formula to start with. The user can type in any value only if B1 is evaluated to zero

Comment: like already mentioned, you cant use data validation on outputs from vlookup

Comment: It's working as desired by the formula in data validation =or(S2128=0,Q2128 <= S2128)

Comment: The above formula is not always working. I modified the validation formula slightly (for the range Q2:Q                   =or((S2:S)=0,((Q2:Q)-(S2:S))<=0 )         ........ It is blocking values higher than contained in S, but allow any value if S=0 (in same row)